# Can you type something automated in AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

So, I already made an AppleScript, that opens an Application, but now I want the AppleScript, to also type something automatically

Here the Script to run Terminal e.g.:

```
tell application "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app" to activate
```

and I want now, that after the Application 'Terminal.app' was opened, it should type `rm -rf` for me. (`rm -rf` is a command where you can delete things)

(and please just post the code, and not ask questions, thanks)

Comment: Take a look at commands in the scripting dictionaries for **Terminal** (`do script`, for example) and **System Events** (`keystroke`, for example).

Comment: FYI You do not need to use the _fully qualified pathname_ of the _application bundle_, simply `tell application "Terminal" to activate` does the job.

Comment: @user3439894 I just drag & drop the terminal from the Application Folder into the script, so it automatically put that long Path, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I finally found an answer.

So this is my code now:

```
tell application "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "rm -rf"
end tell
```

Comment: You could have also just done something like `tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo 'this is a test'"`.

Answer (score -1):

As red_menace already mentioned, you could also do:

```
do shell script "rm -rf"
```

The UI scripting contained in the current answer has the tendency of failing. You also have to deal with the open terminal window, the enter key isn't pressed and the list goes on. With AppleScript, there is rarely the need to do  UI scripting.